# Install ceiling fan w/o installing receiver for remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

Installed new remote control ceiling fan with light in a room with a separate fan switch and light switch and it doesn't work.

Comment: What make and model is the fan? Can you post photos of the wiring?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you've also posted the same question [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/89848), but under a [different account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/96422/steve). This is confusing, to say the least. Please use the SE contact form to request that the accounts be merged

Comment: What is the question? Howto intall without remote receiver or why it won't turn on?