# 3 way switch ceiling fan and light

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan

My old ceiling fan had the light switched 3 way and the fan on a separate single switch. my new fan w/remote does not account for this and there is no place to connect the red from the junction box to the new fan & light. Is there a way to install so the light will work off of 2 switches and the fan on a separate switch like the old one? I was going to try connecting the red to the black but don't want to fry the kit.

Comment: What make/model fan?

Comment: I don't get it. what about the remote?  How does that figure in to your plan?

Comment: What make and model is the fan? Can you post the installation instructions, for that matter?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you've also posted the same question [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156233), but under a [different account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/96418/cutter54). This is confusing, to say the least. Please use the SE contact form to request that the accounts be merged.

Comment: Sorry, I had signed off. I appreciate the responses. The fan is a Harbor Breeze Sail Stream, with remote. Installation was very straight forward, connect black to black, white to white, ground to ground., Then when connecting the light, it had quick connectors for black and white from fan motor to light. Doesn't seem to be any way to operate the light separately on a 3 way.

Comment: Daniel, that post is not from me.

Comment: Harper, the remote works fine, it's just I prefer to avoid having 2 dead switches that previously operated the light.

Comment: Help us by sketching a simple wiring diagram of what you have there. Take a picture of it and post it so we can get a better understanding.